# Hosting a MySQL server on Amazon Web Services

Tags: mysql, web, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

We are evaluating hosting our application on Amazon EC2 service. While I am confident that a Small instance (1.7GB RAM) will be sufficient for our web server (at this point), I am not sure about requirements for the MySQL server:

- Would it make sense to put the MySQL server on the same image as our main server? (to save costs)
- I suppose The database will be constantly updated and queried from multiple sources other than the web server, up to 100,000 queries a day / 5000 updates a day. If deploying via RDS, should the database be deployed on an image that has more resources than a "small" instance?
- Would it ever make sense to host a MySQL database on EC2 but not via RDS?

Thanks,